# Intl.DateTimeFormat() with format options doesn't work for 'it-CH'

Tags: javascript, date

I get a locale from the server and try to format a given date based on this locale formatting options and additional options. It works with all locales, but `it-CH`

```
date = new Date(2010,0,1)
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH', {day:'2-digit', month:'2-digit', year:'numeric'}).format(date)
// output: "01.01.2010"
```

The correct output should be `01/01/2010`

It works though for locale `it`:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it', {day:'2-digit', month:'2-digit', year:'numeric'}).format(date)
// output: "01/01/2010"
```

Or with the locale `it-CH` if I don't include the year formatting in options:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH', {day:'2-digit', month:'2-digit'}).format(date)
// output: "01/01"
```

The correct output should be `01/01/2010`. I tested it on Window and Mac OS in the latest versions of Chrome.
Where this strange behaviour comes from, how can I fix it?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), `dd.mm.yyyy` is indeed the correct date format in Switzerland for all the official languages German, French, Italian, and Romanish. Why do you think it should be `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: @str—while wikipedia is helpful, it [shouldn't be quoted as a normative reference](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2009/10/how-to-cite-wikipedia-in-apa-style.html). There is no standardised mapping of date formats to language tags. They also change over time due to various influences, and different formats might be used by different communities that all speak the same language in the same geographic region, hence the recommendation to us an unambiguous format in an appropriate language.

Comment: @RobG That is true but I did not find any other more trustable or official source for this. But what I can tell is that I live in Switzerland (German-speaking part, though) and I have never seen `dd/mm/yyyy` being used in Switzerland for anything major regardless of the language. Even the Italian versions of admin.ch (the website of the federal council) and srf.ch (the largest radio and TV station) use `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: @str—your first–hand experience means much more to me than the wikipedia reference. :-)

Comment: @str You're right. The output `"1/1/2010"` from the function `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH').format(new Date(2010,0,1))` got my thinking wrong. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the actual formatting of dates by *toLocaleString* is largely [implementation dependent](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/#annex-implementation-dependent-behaviour), so while it may be consistent for the most common languages and variants, it's not so good for those that are less common or where multiple date formats are commonly used (which is the case where I live).

The situation is quite complex. The "locale" is a [BCP 47 language tag](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47). The list of [tags and subtags](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) is maintained by IANA and changes from time–to–time. Further, the mapping of formats to tags and subtags is implementation dependent.

The bottom line is that there is uncertainty over what format should apply to a particular language and variant, and a huge number of local languages and variants (e.g. tribal languages) are not supported at all. So don't rely on *toLocaleString* doing all the work and getting it right all the time.

An alternative to leaving it all up to the implementation is to manually format the date in an unambiguous format using *toLocaleString* for the language of the individual components. That way where a specific language isn't supported, you can fall back to the browser default language (see PPS below) and be confident that what you're putting on the page is clear and not leaving it entirely to the implementation, e.g.

```js
function getFormattedDate(d, lang){
  return d.getDate().toLocaleString(lang) + ' '
    + d.toLocaleString(lang, {month:'long'}) + ', '
    + d.toLocaleString(lang, {year:'numeric'});
}

var d = new Date();
['it-CH', 'en-GB', 'ar-EG', 'zu-ZA', 'hz', undefined].forEach(
  lang => console.log((lang||'Default') +
          ': ' + getFormattedDate(d, lang))
);
```

Don't get too hung up over supporting every possible format and language variant. It's far more important to ensure dates are unambiguous than whether the components are separated by commas, dashes, slashes or whatever the local variant uses customarily. As I look at formal correspondence in my locale, dates are represented in 3 or 4 different formats, often two different formats are used on the same page (e.g. in headers, text and tabular data).

**PS**: You should also [test for support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Examples) for *toLocaleString* before using it.

**PPS**: It would be really good if there was a way to test if a language tag is supported before using it, but as far as I can tell that's not possible. E.g. in the example above, "hz" is [Herero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herero_people), a language spoken by a particular ethnic group in southern Africa and likely not supported by any browser, so it should fall back to the browser default language.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using the intl polyfill module to completely replace NodeJS’s implementation of intl.

First run `npm i --save intl`

Then you need to replace Intl by polyfill:

```
Intl = require("intl")
```

That's it. Now you can try:

```
const date = new Date();
const options = {
        year: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric'
    };
const dateFormatted = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR', options).format(date);
console.log(dateFormatted);
```

// expected output: 24/09/2019 17:43